# Can't use the UPDATE command to update my SQL Server database from an ASP.NET textbox

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm working on a code where I am trying to develop a Profile page that displays data from a database based on an id used from a log in page. I'm using VS 2019 and I used the built in database system to create the database. Right now I am stuck where I can't update the database using an ASP.NET textbox.

This is the code for the button that saves the changes to a 'user' table:

```
protected void btnUserSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string user_id = Session["user_id"].ToString();

    if (tbUserName != null)
    {
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BasketballConStr"].ConnectionString;

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            string query = "UPDATE user SET username = @username WHERE user_id = @user_id";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user_id", user_id);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", tbUserName.Text);

            cmd.Connection.Open();

            try
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Error " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason, I keep getting an error that says

> System.Exception: 'Error Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'user'.'

I searched a lot and many people suggested to add the WHERE part of the query in a bracket like below:

```
UPDATE user 
SET username = @username 
WHERE user_id = (@user_id)
```

Yet, I still keep getting the same error.

Your help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried running this sql query directly on database ? Is it working fine ?

Comment: Enclose user table name in square brackets like this [user]

Comment: [User](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/user-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is a reserved term for SQL.

Comment: `User` is a reserved word. You shouldn't be using it as a table name. If you insist on complicating every SQL statement that touches it by doing so, you need to wrap it in square brackets like `[user]`. It's a bad table name anyway - it's singular, which means that it appears it contains one user record. If you insist on using that name, your table name should at least be `users` (plural).

Comment: @HammadShabbir I did try to run the query on the database and it showed the same error. But after I tried your solution it worked perfectly. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @YongShun ya just found out and it works perfectly now with the square brackets. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @KenWhite actually I would hate to complicate things and I understand how changing the name would be better. But I'm working on this with a couple of my friends and I would have to discuss this with them first (which is honestly something we need to fix). Thank you so much for the clarification

Comment: Don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Answer (score 0):

You should use in this way;

```
UPDATE [user]
SET username = @username 
WHERE user_id = (@user_id)
```